# Porting a portrait-only app to work for both screen orientations

Tags: android

This a general query.
I will be beginning to port a portrait-only app to work for both landscape and portrait screen orientations.
Is there any document that addresses this process specifically?
I will be using native views - so i am not expecting any issues with any resources files such as drawables, etc
I do have one screen in the application that plays video clips - my fear is how to make the video to keep playing while the orientation changes.
Also, wondering if i will have to save any activity states/variables while orientation occurs.
So, these are some of my concerns and i was wondering if there are any thumbrules or documentation i could read up on before plunging into porting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read application fundamentals and what happens while orienting the application. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

If you want a faster orientation change you can read this document http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

If you keep your variables static in activity than you can get them in which method you want automatically.